# How to get the cursor to the end of a command after using TeXstudio Macro with insert

Tags: macros, texstudio

I created a macro in TexStudio:

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.StartOfWord)
editor.write("Some Text ")
cursor.shift(cursorEnums.EndOfWord)
```

Supposed behavior (works well most times):

```
someWord|
Some Text someWord|
```

*"|" should denote the position of the courser. First line before, second line after running the macro.*

Behavior for very long Words:

```
veryLongWordLongerThenInputIGuess|
Some Text veryLongWordLongerTh|enInputIGuess
```

Can someone reproduce this?
Can someone explain me what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
cursor.shift(cursorEnums.EndOfWord)
```

to

```
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.EndOfWord)
```

See the documentation of related methods of `cursor` object in [User Manual of TeXstudio, section 4.5.3](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#JAVASCRIPT-MACROS).

Comment: Oh jeez, sorry. I was blind. I figured it out before and now I wasn't able to see it. Thank you.